# Android App Crashes on App start without any exception

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The app crashes on RealMe Device :
Android 10

I have 4 API's at the app start I am calling it using I need to load all API data before launching AppShell. Below I have given sample code of how I did, please let me know where I am wrong.

```
public App()
{
   LoadInitialData();
   MainPage = new AppShell();
}

async void LoadInitialData()
{
    try
    { 
        var langList =  task1;
        var staticList = task2;
        var loadFilter = task3;
        var loadInitialData = task4;
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

async Task task1()
{
try
{
    var data = await APIService();
    // ...Operations
}
catch(Exception ex){
}
```

similar for task 2, 3 and 4;

Removing the API call at app start works but it cause crash on some physical devices
Working fine on emulator and simulators.

App crashed after the last line on the output console: **Requested dump for tid 19224**

I am not able to fix this issue Please help me out.

Below I had attached the console output

> ```
> [ANR_LOG] >>> msg's executing time is too long
> [ANR_LOG] >>>Current msg List is:
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <1> = { when=-8s986ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction TopResumedActivityChangeItem, hashCode, mActivityToken = android.os.BinderProxy@8397486 mLifecycleStateRequest null mActivityCallbacks [TopResumedActivityChangeItem{onTop=true}] }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <2> = { when=-8s581ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <3> = { when=-8s580ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <4> = { when=-3s978ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@8397486 }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <5> = { when=-3s978ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@8397486 }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <6> = { when=-2s521ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <7> = { when=-1s546ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <8> = { when=-1s546ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor }
> [ANR_LOG] Blocked msg = { when=-8s987ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction LaunchActivityItem,ResumeActivityItem hashCode, mActivityToken = android.os.BinderProxy@8397486 mLifecycleStateRequest ResumeActivityItem{procState=-1,updateProcState=false,isForward=true} mActivityCallbacks [LaunchActivityItem{intent=Intent { cmp=app.trigyn.intgovforum/crc64c380bed34e83dfdf.MainActivity mCallingUid=10650 },ident=231122137,info=ActivityInfo{d45d982 crc64c380bed34e83dfdf.MainActivity},curConfig={1.0 ??mcc??mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h752dp 480dpi nrml long hdr widecg port night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 76 - 1080, 2340) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.1mThemeChanged= 0, mThemeChangedFlags= 0, mFlipFont= 0, mAccessibleChanged= -1, mUxIconConfig= 1163076078932590657, mMaterialColor= 0, mUserId= 0, mFo08-26 13:56:51.506 E/ANR_LOG (19224): Current msg <9> = { when=-1s546ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor }
> [ANR_LOG] Current msg <10> = { when=-1s546ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor }
> [Choreographer] Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> [OplusZoomWindowDecorViewHelper] setLastReportedMergedConfiguration mZoomDisplayHeight: 2340 getDecorView.DecorView@8dacdcf[MainActivity]
> [gyn.intgovforu] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 14955(1026KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3461KB/6923KB, paused 30us total 10.202ms
> [OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=2679ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=5696483915746, Vsync=5697933915688, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=5697950512252, AnimationStart=5697950569075, PerformTraversalsStart=5697951128658, DrawStart=5699115447981, SyncQueued=5699151679803, SyncStart=5699152084126, IssueDrawCommandsStart=5699152227251, SwapBuffers=5699161770428, FrameCompleted=5699163866783, DequeueBufferDuration=151094, QueueBufferDuration=1778854, GpuCompleted=0, 
> Resolved pending breakpoint at 'UtilityFunction.cs:789,1' to void igf.Utility.UtilityFunction.<>c.<<LoadInitialRequiredData>b__34_0>d.MoveNext () [0x00482].
> [Choreographer] Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> [OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=1261ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=5697963051789, Vsync=5699196385073, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=5699207004595, AnimationStart=5699207069908, PerformTraversalsStart=5699207592095, DrawStart=5699219977616, SyncQueued=5699221474439, SyncStart=5699221734283, IssueDrawCommandsStart=5699221844960, SwapBuffers=5699223017303, FrameCompleted=5699224405689, DequeueBufferDuration=120677, QueueBufferDuration=1087396, GpuCompleted=0, 
> Thread started: <Thread Pool> #18
> [gyn...] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 27372(1075KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3847KB/7695KB, paused 30us total 11.959ms
> Thread started: <Thread Pool> #19
> Thread started: <Thread Pool> #20
> Thread started: <Thread Pool> #21
> [gyn...] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 2376(210KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3877KB/7754KB, paused 31us total 11.952ms
> [libc] Requested dump for tid 19224 (gyn....)
> ```

Comment: Try to run 4 tasks one by one to see where is wrong? Or post more your code.

Comment: have you added any exception handling or logging?

Comment: @Shaw I tried doing that but then also the app is crashing on my personal device Realme X2 pro. Even tough I tried hitting single API then also crashing

Comment: @Jason I added code exception handling for uncatched code in android Native project but it is not capturing the exception.

Comment: have you added any exception handling to the individual tasks?

Comment: @Jason yes i did but I am not getting any exception directly app is crashed but one thing is app is loaded but after 3-4 seconds it crashes.

Comment: @Shaw I had added more of my code plz let me know Where I am going wrong

Comment: your `catch` block is empty, how is that helpful?  Add some logging or at least a `Console.Writeline(ex)`

Comment: In the actual code base it is written but the exception is not captured

Comment: @khushalMistry It is not a crash, it is an ANR and thus the OS is terminating your app.

Comment: 1. Is your app ok with `LoadInitialData` method commented out, didn't see your `InitializeComponent` call? 2. What about running  `await task1();` only in your `LoadInitialData` method?

Comment: @SushiHangover how do i stop that can you please help me out?